# Prove a set has cardinality $\aleph$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A be the set of all numbers between $0$ and $1$ so that each number's infinite decimal representation is comprised of only odd numbers after the decimal point (For example: $0.1351379...$)

Prove that $|A| = \aleph$

Comment: What do you mean by Alef? Do you mean $|\Bbb R|$?

Comment: What does “Alef” mean?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Why do you think that Alef would be $\aleph_1$?

Comment: Just a hunch. Maybe I’m wrong.

Comment: Because Alef sounds like aleph, that set does have cardinality $\aleph_1$ and I don’t see what else his question could be about. But like I said, I could be wrong about what his intended question was.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, Alef is an alternative transliteration of $\aleph$. I am just not sure why you're so adamant on $\aleph_1$.

Comment: I thought $\aleph$ was non-specific. Is $\aleph$ a synonym of $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @Adam: $\aleph$ is sometimes used to denote the cardinality of $\Bbb R$. That is **not** the definition of $\aleph_1$.

Comment: I see. I thought that was the definition of $\aleph_1$. So is it best to just use $|\mathbb{R}|$?

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, in my answer, I am not working in binary, I'm working in usual decimals base $10$.

It is well-known that the set $B$ of all numbers between $0$ and $1$ whose decimal expansion contains only $0$’s and $1$’s is an uncountable set, by Cantor’s diagonalisation argument. For example, this is proven in Rudin's PMA Theorem 2.14.

Your question is not so different...

For example map every $0$ digit after the decimal point to $3$ and every $1$ digit after the decimal point to $7$. e.g. $f: 0.00110100101001... \to 0.33773733737337...$.

This is a bijection.

Therefore the set of numbers between $0$ and $1$ whose decimal expansions only contain $3$ and $7$ is uncountable.

$A$ is a superset of this set, so A must also be uncountable.

[I learned in the comments that "uncountable" does *not* mean the same thing as "cardinality at least $|\mathbb{R}|$", because this would assume the c.h. which we do not implicitly assume to be true (if we assume the c.h. is true (or false) then we must state so). But for this question we don't need to address the c.h. at all.]

It can also be shown that there exists an injective function $f: \mathbb{R} \to B$, therefore $ \mathbb{R}$ and $B $ do have the same cardinality.

So by the "sandwich theorem" $|B| = |A| = |\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the bijection. Let me clarify by editing my answer

Comment: I never said it was bijective with $A$. Read the end of my answer.

Comment: I'm not working in binary... I'm working in the usual base $10$

Comment: OK, I understand your point.

Comment: How do you know that it's $\aleph_1$?

Comment: More pointedly, it *doesn’t* have cardinality $\aleph_1$, unless of course the reals have cardinality $\aleph_1$. (cf. the continuum hypothesis.) It has cardinality of the reals. Denoted $2^{\aleph_0}$, or $\beth_1$, or (apparently... Asaf’s comment on OP is the first I’ve heard of this notation) $\aleph$.

Comment: I thought in general we assume the c.h. is true unless otherwise stated. My bad then. I’ll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Adam Nope. It rarely comes up outside set theory, but when a theorem uses the continuum hypothesis the result  is stated as “CH implies X”, not “X is true”. Kinda like with the Riemann Hypothesis, only unlike RH, CH isn’t generally believed to be true. It’s not even universally agreed upon if it has an absolute truth value (though it’s my understanding that the dominant ideology amongst set theorists is that it has an absolute truth value and is false... an understanding that may be outdated and oversimplified.)

Comment: So, uncountable does not mean the same as "at least the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: @Adam Nope, it just means “not countable”. In other words, that there is no injective function from the set into the natural numbers.

Comment: Ok, so my answer is wrong then because, all I have shown is that set $A$ has cardinality between that of the set of all decimals with digits $0$ and $1$, which I have not shown to have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, and the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. In fact, is it even true that the set of all decimal expansions with digits $0$ and $1$ only has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$? Without assuming c.h is true, we would need to construct an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to the $1$ and $0$ set. Ah, does every real number have a unique binary representation?

Comment: @Adam Yes, roughly speaking, you can map any number like this to the number it would be if the notation were base two, thus can get a one-to-one correspondence with a real interval.

Comment: Ah so every number does have a binary representation but it is not necessarily unique. But like you say, there are ways to get round this in order to show such an injection exists. Thanks for your help.